# How to sort sequence of numeric data type in scala

Tags: scala

I am newbie to scala and for practice I am trying to write a generic function that calculates median for sequence of integer or doubles.
Below is the snippet of the code :

```
implicit class trial[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
    def median[T](implicit num: Fractional[T]):Double = {
      import num._

      seq.sorted match {

        case x if x.length % 2 != 0 => x(x.length / 2).toDouble()
        case x => (x(x.length / 2).toDouble() + x(x.length / 2 - 1).toDouble()) / 2

      }

    }
  }
```

In the above code sorted function is not working saying implicit ordering can not be found.Can some one guide me on how can we sort the list of numerics in scala?

Edit ==>

After going through answers on this post I have changed my code(changed code is pasted below) and now this is working for Ints and Doubles,but now if in future If I have to support BigDecimals then what changes will I have to make?

```
implicit class GenericMedian[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
    def median(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = {
      import num._
      val medianPosition = seq.length / 2
      seq.sortWith(num.gt) match {
        case x if x.length % 2 != 0 => x(medianPosition)
        case x => (x(medianPosition).toDouble() + x(medianPosition - 1).toDouble()) / 2
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Your proposed solution is not a good one. Because you are trying to return type `T` for an odd length `seq`, and return type `Double` for an even length `seq`, the compiler has to compromise and return type `Any`, which is not what you want. Try doubling a `.median` result and see what you get: `Seq(1,2,3).median*2`

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me on **Scala 2.13**

```
implicit class trial[T](private val seq: Seq[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def median(implicit num: Integral[T]): T = {
    import num._

    val sorted = seq.sorted
    val length = sorted.length
    val medianPosition = length / 2

    if ((length % 2) == 0)
      sorted(medianPosition)
    else
      (sorted(medianPosition) + sorted(medianPosition + 1)) / num.fromInt(2)
  }
}
```

I forgot to mention that the only real problem with your code *(at least in terms of compilation)* is that since you are defining a new `T` type variable on the definition of the method. You can not sort the sequence with that implicits, because for the compiler those were two different types.

Comment: Shouldn't median of [1,2] be 1.5 instead of 2 since there is even number of elements? Also this does not seem to work with integers.

Comment: @MarioGalic I leave the logic as OP presented it. Since the problem was the definition of the method itself, not the implementation. And for the Integer part, yeah that is a problem, but one can easily provide their own implementation of **Fractional** for **Int**. On the other hand, fixing the return type to **Double** is a more dangerous error _(IMHO)_, since you are capping the precision of the algorithm to something different from the input data. What if, the sequence was of **BigDecimals**?

Comment: @MarioGalic using **Integral** instead of **Fractional** it should handle **Ints** too.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you are correct my method was shadowing the type parameter and it was causing the problem.But,if we use integral types then the method won't be able to support doubles,I read this on https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-data-types-bits-ranges-int-short-long-float-double

Comment: @Hitesh Oh, yes my bad. I read bad the source and get confused. You have to either chose one _(**Fractional** or **Integral**)_ or implement both methods.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `Numeric` typeclass to handle both integers and doubles

```
implicit class MedianSeq[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
  def median(implicit num: Numeric[T]): Option[Double] = {
    val sorted = seq.sorted
    val fractionalMidpoint: Double = sorted.size / 2.0

    sorted.size match {
      case x if x < 2 => None
      case x if x == 2 => Some(num.toDouble(num.plus(seq(0), seq(1))) / 2)
      case x =>
        if (fractionalMidpoint % 2 != 0.0) {
          Some(num.toDouble(sorted(fractionalMidpoint.toInt)))
        } else {
          val a = sorted(fractionalMidpoint.toInt - 1)
          val b = sorted(fractionalMidpoint.toInt)
          Some(num.toDouble(num.plus(a, b)) / 2)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

which outputs

```
Seq(3,5,2,34,5,6,7,87,8).median == Some(6.0) // true
Seq(1,2,3,4).median == Some(2.5) // true
Seq(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0).median == Some(2.5) // true
Seq(1,2).median == Some(1.5) // true
Seq(1,1).median == Some(1.0) // true
Seq(1).median == None // true
```

Note we use [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/median.html) definition of median when there are even number of elements:

> When there are two middle numbers we average them.

hence `Seq(1,2).median == Some(1.5)`

Comment: Solution look good, but say in future If I have to support bigdecimal data type, then what changes will I have to make?By converting BigDecimal to double I may loose the precision.